# Some questions about split_train_test function

Tags: python

I am currently trying to apply Linear Regression model to test the relationship between two variables $X$ and $Y$. Given a dataset with $8$ columns and $1000$ rows, I want to split this dataset into training and test sets using `split_train_test`. But i wonder what is the difference between `split_train_test(dataset, test_size, random_test = int)` vs `split_train_test(dataset, test_size).`Also, does the 2nd one (without setting `random_test=int`) give me a **different** test set and training set each time I re-run my program? Does the 1st one give me the **same** test set and training set every time I re-run my program? What is the difference between setting `random_test=42 vs random_test=43`, for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the  first gives you the same split because you passing a Seed to the random number generator.
If you change the  random  number you get different split. Using seed numbers you can reproduce experiments.